# Rails server url not working with nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to get a list of rentals in a category. in rails console the query works perfectly, but in localhost if I type
http://127.0.0.1:3000/categories/1/rentals
a list of all rentals is returned, even the rentals that dont belong to the category.

in rails console

```
irb(main):002:0> rental.categories
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "rental_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "rental_categories"."category_id" WHERE "rental_categories"."rental_id" = ? /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT ?  [["rental_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Category id: 7, name: "2 bedroom", created_at: "2021-05-31 20:37:58.920051000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-05-31 20:37:58.920051000 +0000">]>
irb(main):003:0>
```

but in rails server

```
Started GET "/categories/6/rentals" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-05-31 20:48:22 +0000
Processing by RentalsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"category_id"=>"6"}
  Rental Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "rentals".* FROM "rentals"
  ↳ app/controllers/rentals_controller.rb:8:in `index'
Completed 200 OK in 78ms (Views: 42.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms | Allocations: 3900)
```

in routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories do
    resources :rentals
  end
  resources :rentals do
    resources :categories
  end
end
```

where have I got wrong?

Comment: What does your `RentalsController#index` action say? Does it actually use the `category_id` parameter? The resource won't be scoped "by magic", you do still need to put correct logic in the controller.

Comment: index action is the default @rentals = Rental.all

Comment: As Tom mentioned, this stuff doesn't happen by magic. `Rental.all` means `select * from rental`. Routes give you access to parameters in the url. So you need to use something like `@rentals = Category.find(params[:category_id]).rentals`. Normally would split this into two lines, but it's a comment, so...

Comment: Also, you don't want the 2nd block in routes. The first one will do.

Comment: Having both blocks of routes isn't necessarily *wrong*, it's just unusual, and probably not what you really wanted. Which routes did you actually **WANT** to define?? You've currently defined **all 4** of: `/categories`, `/categories/<category_id>/rentals`, `/rentals`, `/rentals/<rental_id>/categories` (in addition to duplicates of all the show/edit/update/delete routes).